# How to write differentiation of time delayed bessel function

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

I have the following delay differential equation

```
v''[t] == 1/Q* (2*G BesselJ'[1, v[t - τ]- v'[t]) - v[t]
```

I want to write this equation in two 1st order equations as

```
v'[t] == x[t]
x'[t]== 1/Q(2*G BesselJ'[1, v[t - τ]- x[t]) - v[t]
```

But  how to write the derivative of Bessel's function which is time delayed.Here `τ` is the delay and the value of `τ` can be 2, G=3.55, Q=69.Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[x, v, τ, eqn1, eqn2]
eqn1 = v''[t] == 1/Q*(2*G D[BesselJ[1, v[t - \[Tau]] - v'[t]], t]) - v[t];

eqn2 = {v'[t] == x[t], eqn1 /. {v'[t] -> x[t], v''[t] -> x'[t]}}
```

[image]

If needed, you can also process the second equation to get `x'[t]` on one side of the equation:

```
eqn3 = {v'[t] == x[t], Equal@@First@Solve[#, x'[t]][[1]] &[
 eqn1 /. {v'[t] -> x[t], v''[t] -> x'[t]}]}
```

to get

[image]

Comment: But how to take the differentiation of the bessels function that I wanted to learn because here it is a time delayed function. Should I expand this as one do for J'1(x).

Comment: @Udichi, if  you  want to differentiate `BesselJ` with respect to first argument you can do `D[BesselJ[x, v[t - \[Tau]] - v'[t]], x] /. x -> 1`

Comment: I want to take the derivative with respect to time

Comment: @Udichi, use `D[BesselJ[1, v[t - \[Tau]] - v'[t]], t]`, I updated my answer based on this information.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Udichi, my pleasure.